# AngularJS + Bootstrap: dropdown list not populating correctly

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I could sure use some guidance on this... I've got a simple Bootstrap dropdown list that doesn't seem to be populating properly, whether I use ng-repeat to retrieve the list from the model OR list the items manually.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <a href="#/{{selectedAction.id}}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="submit()"> {{selectedAction.name}}</button></a>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="caret"></span></button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                    <li ng-repeat="action in actions">
                        <a href="#" ng-click="setAction(action)">{{action.name}}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
        </div><!-- /btn-group -->
    </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
</div><!-- /.row -->
```

Also, more importantly, the ng-click directive should change the DOM via normal binding, but this doesn't seem to work either.

```
var DropDownApp = angular.module('DropDownApp', []);

DropDownApp.controller('DropDownCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.actions = [
        {id: 'action1', name: 'Action 1'},
        {id: 'action2', name: 'Action 2'},
        {id: 'action3', name: 'Action 3'}
    ];

    $scope.selectedAction = $scope.actions[0];

    $scope.setAction = function(action) {
        $scope.selectedAction = action;
        console.log("selected==>", $scope.selectedAction);
        $scope.submit();
    };

    $scope.submit = function() {
        console.log($scope.selectedAction.id);
    };
}]);
```

You can see the code behavior here: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1yrrVFBeXhP4O7cYSLFw?p=preview)

Comment: You haven't included `ui.bootstrap` in your module dependency list, nor have you used the `uib-dropdown` directive. See https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note the points below:

- Include `ui.bootstrap` dependancy in app.js to work with Angular ui-bootstrap.
- This directive is composed by three parts:

  1. `uib-dropdown` which transforms a node into a dropdown.
  2. `uib-dropdown-toggle` which allows the dropdown to be toggled via click. This  directive is optional.
  3. `uib-dropdown-menu` which transforms a node into the popup menu.
     Each of these parts need to be used as attribute directives.

Please find the working plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/v2uonllub3GsTFUxdFys?p=preview

Cheers!

Comment: Varit05, I appreciate your feedback.  It worked!!  Would have never figured this out w/ your help!!